# Best serif web font for wide variety of scripts/glyphs

Tags: web-fonts, serif

I'm developing a site with mixed content in a bunch of different scripts, mainly Latin, Cyrillic and Hebrew. There's also content in languages such as Lithuanian with an interesting variety of diacritics.

Whilst working on the design (in an extremely amateurish fashion) I was hoping to find a serif font for the main headings to compliment the sans serif base font. The Adelle font, as used by sites like the [BFI](http://bfi.org.uk) looked great, but it appears to be exceedingly expensive. The vaguely similar (and free) [Bitter](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Bitter) font looks decent in Latin but seems to have no support for alternative scripts.

[Roboto Slab](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Slab) *does* support Cyrillic (at least) but diacritics look very dodgy.

To be honest, certain diacritics seem to look bad in almost everything I've tried except the standard Nimbus Sans that is the default for my CSS framework. (I do not like its standard serif font - Liberation Serif - at all.)

My question is essentially: is there a good Adelle-like serif font with nice consistent support for a lot of glyphs?

Comment: For a good font you will have to pay, because it is a lot of work to create good looking (what ever this is for you) fonts with all the glyphs.

Comment: You should look into the PT superfamily. It was designed to support every Cyrillic variation (no Hebrew unfortunatly).

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Really No. 2" from Linotype. It has Hebrew, and also Cyrillic etc. it was designed by Gary Munch.

http://www.linotype.com/en/517518/ReallyNo2-family.html

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly like Adelle, but [Noto Serif](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Noto+Serif) supports Latin, Greek & Cyrillic and there is a [Noto Sans Hebrew](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess) that could complement it